# Power BI -- Line chart -- Basic filtering -- Require single selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Line Chart in Power BI. I'm doing basic filtering on the year, so it shows all years between 2013 and 2020. I want the chart to only display one year at a time, so I check the Require single selection box. But is there a way to have it select the year dynamically based on the result of a measure?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a filter on "visual level" either based on a measure or a calculated column.
If the visual is of type slicer you can only use a calculated column and not calculated measures.
E.g. if you create a calculated column "isCurrentYear" in your date table you can use that for filtering. based on which criteria you want to choose the year?

Comment: Thanks, Jochen.  I should preface this by admitting that I'm a Power BI newbie, learning things as I go along.  Maybe what I'm trying to do can't be done, I don't know.  I have a What If parameter for the desired year and I'd like to filter the Line Chart to only show data for the year the user selects.  Do I do something in DAX?  DirectQuery?